# How to implement table virtualization and infinite scroll for Material-Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table, react-virtualized

I have to implement virtualization and inifnite scroll with Material-Table, while preserving all its capabilities, such as selection, draggable columns, styling etc.

I was following this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/virtualized-material-table-28umv. However, it seems to fail when selection comes in to play.

Does anybody have any working example for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply forgot to pass the onClick handler to the TableBody onRowClick prop. So creating a handler and then passing it in line #108
`onRowClick={onRowClick}`